# Would like to pass a session variable through a URL

Tags: asp-classic

I have a session variable within my ASP page

```
<% =Session("emplname") %>
```

How can I pass a session variable within a URL? Would it be similar to

```
<a href="divProgLog.asp?emp=& emplname &" class="category">Division 1</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="divProgLog.asp?emp=<%=Session("emplname")%>" class="category">Division 1</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the point of the session variable so that you can access it on any page without the need to pass it on manually? If you really want to pass it you could do a response.write and write it out like this.

```
<a href="divProgLog.asp?emp=<% response.write(Session("emplname")) %>" class="category">Division 1</a>
```

This will write the session into the queryString. Hope this helps.

Comment: If the receiving page is not running ASP-Classic, or not located on the same server you may need to pass some session information via other means. Not saying that is the case here, or at least with the sample code provided, but just to address the initial part of your answer.

Comment: Having said all that, I do agree that if @Jimmy is running the page in the same app pool on the same server, there shouldn't be a need to pass the information via query string.